# Making powershell run downloaded program

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run Microsoft Online Services Sign-In Assistant which have been downloaded using powershell web request cmdlet.

I've just started the script and stuck in this part - which is supposed to start the downloaded program.

here is the code:

```
$link = Invoke-WebRequest https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/0/1/5017D39B-8E29-48C8-91A8-8D0E4968E6D4/en/msoidcli_64.msi

$DLPath= ($ENV:USERPROFILE) + "\Downloads\" + ($link.split("/")[8])

Write-Host "Microsoft sign in assistance" -foregroundcolor yellow
Start-BitsTransfer -Source $Link -Destination $DLPath

Start-Process -FilePath $DLPath -Wait
```

I have an error in the $DLPath part

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $DLPath= ($ENV:USERPROFILE) + "\Downloads\" + ($link.split("/")[8])
Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebResponseObject] does not contain a method named 'split'.
At line:1 char:1
+ $DLPath= ($ENV:USERPROFILE) + "\Downloads\" + ($link.split("/")[8])
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

the point of this script that in the end i will be able to share it with my colleague and they would have the ability to connect to the office 365
for our clients and manage the office 365 account for every individual client

Comment: You should define the path to where the msi should be saved first and then use this for 'OutFile' on 'Invoke-WebRequest'. In your current script you don't save the file anywhere but save the whole webrespone as $link. I assume you wanted link to be the path of the downloaded file ?

Comment: but i did define it in this way `$DLPath= ($ENV:USERPROFILE) + "\Downloads\" + ($link.split("/")[8])`

if you have any other way, i would very happy to see your idea,
thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
$link = "https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/0/1/5017D39B-8E29-48C8-91A8-8D0E4968E6D4/en/msoidcli_64.msi"
$DLPath = Join-Path $ENV:USERPROFILE (join-path "Downloads" (Split-Path $link-Leaf))

Invoke-WebRequest $link -OutFile $DLPath

Write-Host "Microsoft sign in assistance" -foregroundcolor yellow
Start-Process -FilePath $DLPath -Wait
```

i dropped the "start-bitstransfer" because i download the file with "invoke-webrequest" already

Comment: Thanks alot for your help.

What's the `$downloadUri` stands for? i didn't use it in my script

Comment: woops, i edited my script but didn't add this change here, correcting this now

Comment: @WebsGhost should be "$link", i updated my script but not the answer here, now this should be fixed ^^